# Python: How to remove elements with a specific key if none value exists in OrderedDict

Tags: python

I need to remove an elements in the output of OrderedDict if a specific key has a special value 'none'.
I need if Data2 and Data3 if both contains None as entry, will remove the elements.

```
    # if both Data2 and Data3 is None
    Key_to_check = [Data2,Data3]

    Output=[OrderedDict([('index', 78), ('Name', u'Andy'), ('Data1', u'Taken'), ('Data2', u'Taken'),('Data3', u'Taken'),
OrderedDict([('index', 609), ('Name', u'Sam'), ('Data1', u'Taken'), ('Data2', None),('Data3', u'Taken'),
OrderedDict([('index', 680), ('Name', u'John'), ('Data1', u'Taken'), ('Data2', None),('Data3', None)]
```

Since John has Data 2 and Data 3 which is None, it will be remove. How can I get the output to remove it?

```
Output=[OrderedDict([('index', 78), ('Name', u'Andy'), ('Data1', u'Taken'), ('Data2', u'Taken'),('Data3', u'Taken'),
    OrderedDict([('index', 609), ('Name', u'Sam'), ('Data1', u'Taken'), ('Data2', None),('Data3', u'Taken')]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try:

```
temp= {k:v for k,v in Data2.items() if (v is not None) or (Data3.get(k, 'Not Existed') is not None)}
Data3 = {k:v for k,v in Data3.items() if (v is not None) or (Data2.get(k, 'Not Existed') is not None)}
Data2 = temp
```

Or shorter version:

```
Data2, Data3 = {k:v for k,v in Data2.items() if (v is not None) or (Data3.get(k, 'Not Existed') is not None)}, {k:v for k,v in Data3.items() if (v is not None) or (Data2.get(k, 'Not Existed') is not None)}
```

Comment: Input data: `Data2 = {'index': '1', 'a': None}`

`Data3 = {'index': None, 'a': None}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this list comprehension:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>>
>>> Output=[OrderedDict([('index', 78), ('Name', u'Andy'), ('Data1', u'Taken'), ('Data2', u'Taken'),('Data3', u'Taken')]),OrderedDict([('index', 609), ('Name', u'Sam'), ('Data1', u'Taken'), ('Data2', None),('Data3', u'Taken')]),OrderedDict([('index', 680), ('Name', u'John'), ('Data1', u'Taken'), ('Data2', None),('Data3', None)])]
>>>
>>> [i for i in Output if i["Data2"] or i["Data3"]]
[OrderedDict([('index', 78), ('Name', u'Andy'), ('Data1', u'Taken'), ('Data2', u'Taken'), ('Data3', u'Taken')]), OrderedDict([('index', 609), ('Name', u'Sam'), ('Data1', u'Taken'), ('Data2', None), ('Data3', u'Taken')])
```

---

Another way, you can use  Built-in function `any` like this:

```
>>> [i for i in Output if any(i.get("Data{0}".format(j),None) for j in range(2,4))]
[OrderedDict([('index', 78), ('Name', u'Andy'), ('Data1', u'Taken'), ('Data2', u'Taken'), ('Data3', u'Taken')]), OrderedDict([('index', 609), ('Name', u'Sam'), ('Data1', u'Taken'), ('Data2', None), ('Data3', u'Taken')])]
```

If you have Data2,Data3...Data 100, change `range(2,4)` to `range(2,101)`.

[any(iterable)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any)

> Return True if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is
>   empty, return False.

Comment: could you elaborate how it Data2 AND Data3 is None?

Comment: If I have Data2,Data3...Data 100, how to change the code to be use? Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot. `Key =[ 'Points','Scores','Rating']` and `[i for i in Output if any(i.get("Key[j],None) for j in len(Key)]`. Is this workable?

Comment: @behappy Yes, by the way, if this answer helps, please accept it.

Comment: `[i for i in Output if any(i.get("Key[j]",None) for j in len(Key)]` return TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: @behappy Why use `"Key[j]"`? Maybe you need to read the The Python Tutorial.

Comment: How to modify `any(i.get("Data{0}".format(j),None)` if I have a list call `mylist =['Points', 'Score','Rating'] ` which is I want to check if the `none` occurred. There is always a list that I need to check if `None` in the OrderedDict. Thanks