# Python: Remove none item in OrderedDict that contain in a list

Tags: python

I need to remove the elements in OrderedDict if the values is 'None'. The list contains the key that I need to check if it is contains 'None' in their values. If it is all 'None' for the keys, then delete the elements. 
I can make it if the list is short with two inputs. But if the list has 10 inputs or more, the way I did is not right. I need a short command and preferred the command that can run in a very short time as my data is very big.

```
# if all items is None in mylist, delete the element from Output
    mylist = ['Football','Tennis']

    Output=[OrderedDict([('index', 88), ('Name', u'Andie'), ('Basketball', u'Yes'), ('Football', u'No'),('Tennis', u'Yes'),
OrderedDict([('index', 89), ('Name', u'Jackie'), ('Basketball', u'No'), ('Football', None),('Tennis', u'Yes'),
OrderedDict([('index', 90), ('Name', u'Sarah'), ('Basketball', u'No'), ('Football', None),('Tennis', None)]
```

My command work if for short list, but if there are 20 type of sports in the list, this method is not efficient. Also, I need the command to be quick in process.

```
[i for i in Output if i["Football"]!=None and i["Tennis"]!=None]
```

In the example, Sarah will be delete from Output.
If the `mylist = ['Basketball','Tennis','Football', 'Squash','Hockey','Cricket'],` how I should approach this?

Comment: same as this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43860946/python-how-to-remove-elements-with-a-specific-key-if-none-value-exists-in-order

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: How to remove elements with a specific key if none value exists in OrderedDict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43860946/python-how-to-remove-elements-with-a-specific-key-if-none-value-exists-in-order)

Comment: Thanks. I have check out the answer, It did not work

Comment: Also, I need something that work for long inputs.

Comment: Do you need to remove those elements from the dict (in place) or create a new dict? Personally I think your data seems to be in a bit of an odd format and I cant help but think that that will limit your scope for speeding up the operation. For instance why ordered dict? Why do these elements need to be in this order? Also why mix the sport names with the index and name data and what do the different possible values for the sport related keys mean?

Comment: @PaulRooney It is actually sort base on index using OrderedDict. Yes, I need to remove the elements that have all `None` in the OrderedDict. I would at least have a way, as my current way will not work if the `mylist` is long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try filter with any:

```
lst = filter(lambda i: any(i.get(key) for key in mylist), Output)
```

Comment: This will raise `KeyError` if there is no such key in OrderedDict object, it's better to call `i.get(key)`